# Apple Pay Web (using Stripe) not shown in few devices

Tags: stripe-payments, applepay-web

I'm having a weird scenario where 'Apple Pay' button is not shown in few devices and shown only in iPhone SE 2020.

I'm testing in Mobile Safari with real credit card enabled in Payment in Apple ID.

| Working | Not Working |
| --- | --- |
| iPhone SE 2020 | iPhone 6S |
|  | iPhone XR |
|  | iPhone 11 |

Not sure what is that I'm missing, any clues/ideas.

[image: Apple Pay shown in iPhone SE 2020]

[image: Apple Pay not shown]

[Stripe Payments](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay/web/v2#verify-your-domain-to-go-live)

[Apple Pay Support](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/iphone/iph67e89f7c8/ios)

Comment: Are there any errors in your console? Have you met all the prerequisites for using Apple Pay listed [here](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button#html-js-prerequisites) [here](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button?html-or-react=html&platform=html-js-testing-apple-pay#html-js-testing)? Are you located in a country that [supports](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207957) Apple Pay?

Comment: There aren't any errors in console. I've met all the prerequisites. The webpage is hosted in AU and I'm accessing it from IN & supports Apple Pay. What confuses me is, it is working in one device and not on other. Is there any tool to find the setting difference between 2 iPhones.

Comment: India does not support Apple Pay (as per the Apple support document [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT207957)).

Comment: As mentioned above, I'm getting Apple Pay icon in iPhone SE 2020 in India. However it is not working for any other iPhone models in India and Australia (Customer). Need a breakthrough for this, if it is not working at all for all devices then its an issue.

Comment: I'd recommend writing in to [support](https://support.stripe.com/contact) at Stripe, this is too in-depth for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sure, thanks! I'll give it a try and update here, so others can get benefitted.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. All devices accessing from AU but only some see the Apple Pay button. The Simulator for example does not see it but my iPhone 13 mini does. No console errors either.